# Can I have a separate shell switch when compiling?

Tags: shell, compilation

Whenever I use `M-x compile`, I like to have the shell that's running to be configured with `bash -ic` so that I can easily type the compilation command (I switch between languages often, so the building mechanism varies and I need have an interactive shell for appropriate auto-completion and language-specific bash aliases to be activated).

The "easy solution" would be putting the following at the top of my `init.el`:

```
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

However, having an interactive shell messes up a lot of important background tasks when launched by emacs (most importantly, `emerge` doesn't play nicely with it). Furthermore, interactive mode needlessly slows things down.

Is it possible to have one `shell-command-switch` when running `M-x compile`, and another for everything else? As a hacky first step, is it possible to redefine `compile` to first copy the old `shell-command-switch` value, set it to `-ic`, then evaluate the old `compile`, and finally switch the value back?